# how to populate value from database using executescaler using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a database in ms access with table name `regn`.  I want to populate the field name `nocount` using command text and executescaler.  Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
dim i as integer
    If cn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        cn.Close()
    End If
    cn.Open()

    cmd.CommandText = "select nocount from regn where pname='" & PNAMETextBox.Text & "' And fname='" & FNAMETextBox.Text & "' And dob='" & DOBDateTimePicker.Text & "' "
    i = cmd.ExecuteScalar

    cn.Close()
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code(apart from the sql-injection issue and missing using-statements).

Comment: When you say you want to populate value... do you mean you want to retrieve the value of nocount, or do you want to insert or update it's value (since populate could indicate all of those cases depending on how it's used)?  In the above code, I don't see where you're initializing "cmd" (presumably you'd get a null reference unless it's initialized outside that function).

Answer (score 0):

If you display your variable `i` then you can see the first value from `nocount` where the condition given by you is fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes your connection is setup elsewhere which looks like it's the case from the code fragment above.  If you're just wanting to get the "nocount" you'll need the command to be set to the connection.  Here's an example that's parameterized (which will protect your from SQL injection exploits):

```
' Assuming you're initializing the connection elsewhere, this will create the command AND set it's
' connection to your connection
Using cmd As SqlCommand = cn.CreateCommand
        ' Parameterize the SQL so it is protected from SQL injection exploits
    cmd.CommandText = "select nocount from regn where pname=@pname And fname=@fname And dob=@dob"
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pname", PNAMETextBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", FNAMETextBox.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", DOBDateTimePicker.Text)

    ' Execute the SQL retuning the first column of the first row (e.g. the nocount from the query)
    i = cmd.ExecuteScalar
End Using
```

As @Tim Schmelter pointed out, this command is wrapped with a Using which will dispose of it properly when it's done being used (again, I'm ignoring the connection in my example assuming it's setup and disposed of properly elsewhere).